# Which gateway to use for SMS messages when multiple to choose from?

Tags: sms, mms, sms-gateway

Hypothetical: I want to send a single text message to all Verizon phones programmatically. I have [multiple email gateways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways) to use (obtained from the all-reliable wikipedia):

- number@vtext.com
- number@vzwpix.com
- number@message.alltel.com
- number@text.wireless.alltel.com
- number@mms.alltel.net

I don't *think* that I'm **guaranteed** that any one of these will work and/or will still be in service (am I?) and I would not like to have to come back and change anything in the code at a later date.

Is there any way that I can make sure that I only send one text message to a given phone number when there are 5 possible gateways?

Comment: Do you get any kind of message back about success or failure of a send attempt?

Comment: @MattParker Possibly... where were you going with that thought? In order to test for a success or failure I would have to email each one thus violating my use-case by sending more than one text message to a phone number.

Comment: Well, my first thought was a nested loop (or analogous construct in your language).  In the outer loop, iterate through the phone numbers.  For each phone number, iterate over the gateways.  Email the first; did it fail?  Email the second.  If the email succeeds, break the inner loop and go on to the next phone number.

Comment: Alternatively, just email everyone using the first gateway, pipe the failures into a second list and email them using the second gateway, etc.  If you can get a valid success/failure result for the emails, that should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The only way way (that I know of) to ensure you only deliver one message to the recipient is to try each gateway sequentially until a message sends successfully, like some of the comments mentioned.

However, I've been sending a decent volume (>1500) of messages using `@vtext.com` lately and haven't noticed any bounces or downtime during sending. I have no way of knowing if every single message was delivered, but none of my test numbers have dropped a message yet. Most US carriers seem to have decent reliability on their gateways these days.

Just remember that SMS is still considered a best-effort service by most carriers. Even if you get your message to their servers successfully, there's no guarantee that the message will make it to its destination.